# Android "How to show alert, when script getting exception"

Tags: android, json, listview, exception

I am new in Android, i try to create listview from JSON data.

Everyting is ok except i cannot show alert to user when script getting exception.

My goal is, script cheking internet connection first before request to server for get JSON. If there is no connection, then apps show alert to user to turn on their internet connection.

Currently is, when no internet connection, my application show force close dialog and close apps. Help me please ... i'm getting frustration for this :)

This is my main Activity Class:

```
public class HargaActivity extends ListActivity {


//SET URL
private static String url = "http://www.jualanmotor.com/JmApi/DaftarMotor/?username=elis&password=puspasarikeisha";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_data            = "data";
private static final String TAG_Parent          = "Parent";
private static final String TAG_Parent_name     = "parent_name";
private static final String TAG_Category        = "Category";
private static final String TAG_Category_name   = "category_name";
private static final String TAG_product_title   = "product_title";

// contacts JSONArray
JSONArray data = null;

// Hashmap for ListView
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.harga_layout);
    new ProgressTask(HargaActivity.this).execute();
}

private class ProgressTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean>
{
    private ProgressDialog dialog;
    private ListActivity activity;
    private Context context;

    public ProgressTask(ListActivity activity) {
         this.activity = activity;
         context = activity;
         dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        this.dialog.setMessage("Trying get content");
        this.dialog.show();
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success)
    {
         /**
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * */
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(HargaActivity.this, productList,
                R.layout.list_item,
                new String[] {TAG_product_title}, new int[] {
                        R.id.product_title});
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        dialog.dismiss();
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(final String... args){
        // Creating JSON Parser instance
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json;
        json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

        try {
             // Getting Array of Contacts
            data = json.getJSONArray(TAG_data);

            // looping through All Contacts
            for(int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++){
                JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);

                // Parent is again JSON Object
                JSONObject parent       =   c.getJSONObject(TAG_Parent);
                String parent_name      =   parent.getString("name");

                // Category is again JSON Object
                JSONObject category     =   c.getJSONObject(TAG_Category);
                String category_name    =   category.getString("name");
                String product_title    =   parent_name + "-" + category_name;
                // creating new HashMap
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                map.put(TAG_Parent_name, product_title);
                map.put(TAG_Category_name, category_name);
                map.put(TAG_product_title, product_title);
                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                productList.add(map);
            }
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            /*
                         **I WANT TO SHOW ALERT MESSAGE HERE**
                    */
            return false;
        }
    }
}
 }
```

And this my JSONParse.java

```
public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();           

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
runonUithread(new Runnable()
{
   Toast.makeText(ReadWebpageAsynTask.this, "Got Error " + e.getMessage().toString(),  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a variable like

```
boolean error = false;
```

It must be visible for all functions in your AsyncTask.
Set it in your catch block to true;

Then you can show the alert in your postExcecute() funciton.

```
if (error == true){
    // show your allert here
}else{
    // Do things here when everything is ok
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing is you are trying to push AlertDialog (UI element) from not-UI thread (doInBackGround of AsyncTask).

You could use

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

public void run() {
    // show your dialog here :) you can build it both here or somewhere else

    }
    });
   }
}).start();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think an exception is getting raised when there is no internet and you try to access the url. Try moving the following line into the try-catch block just next to it

```
jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
```

This function is being called in doInBackground() for your ProgressTask. Moving it inside the try-catch will ensure if the internet is not available and and exception is raised, you will catch that exception and will be able to display a message to user.

For displaying a message you can either use Toast or AlertDialog from inside the catch block.